# Build ObjectGraph in Javers

Tags: javers

Javers only seems to allow comparison of two distinct entities, while I am looking to make the comparison against the same entity before and after modification.
I am not looking to commit or store history of an entity.

Pseudocode like code:

```
val object = getObjectFromDatabase();
val beforeModification = Javers.createSnapshot(object);
object.setName(...);
object.setValue(...);
val afterModification = Javers.createSnapshot(object);

val diff = Javers.compare(beforeModification, afterModification);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what `javers.commit()` does.
See [Querying for Changes](https://javers.org/documentation/jql-examples/#query-for-changes).

By default, `javers.commit()` uses in-memory Snapshots repository, so you don't need to set up a database and persistent JaversRepository.

Comment: But that in-memory snapshot repository will only grow, isn't it? Since there doesn't seem to be a way to discard the snapshots related to a given entity once the comparison is done and I've obtain the changes (via two consecutive commit calls).

Comment: yes, it's designed mainly for testing and prototyping, for production you should use a repository backed by database, see https://javers.org/documentation/repository-configuration/